# Force react-scripts to use a specific version of sub-dependency

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarnpkg, package.json, react-scripts

I created an application using CRA tool. I get the following error when I try to do `yarn start`.

> The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a
> dependency:
>
> "babel-eslint": "10.1.0"

I have babel-eslint version 10.0.3 installed. And due to some reason I don't want to switch to babel-eslint 10.1.0. I need a way to override babel-eslint dependency inside react-scripts to use 10.0.3 instead.

I reason I don't want to switch to newer version is that this React application resides in in a mono-repo organized repository having several other React applications which are not using CRA and depend on babel-eslint version 10.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

if you cant split them into different repos (which is what I would suggest), you could do the following;

1. downgrade `react-scripts` (and reinit your CRA project) that uses a lower babel-eslint
2. eject from react-scripts via `react-scripts eject` and configure everything to what you need it to be (*warning: this can not be undone!*). This is however problematic since you will need to manage everything yourself and will cause incompatibilities if you just switch versions
3. upgrade your packages that require babel-eslint 10.0.3 to 10.1.0